# How to get quotient and remainder when dividing decimal values?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to separate the value of remainder and quotient.

For example

```
@Qty = 35
@OnHand = 2
@Size = 6

Print (@Qty + @OnHand) / @Size        --(35+2)/6   I should get 6
Print (@Qty + @OnHand) % @Size        --(35+2)%6   I should get 2
```

Suppose if my `@size` & `@OnHand` have a fractional value like this:

```
@Qty = 35
@OnHand = 1.5
@Size = 2.5

Print (@Qty + @OnHand) / @Size     --(35+1.5)/2.5   I should get 14
Print (@Qty + @OnHand) % @Size     --(35+1.5)%2.5   I should get 1.5
```

But when I try with T-SQL, it is not showing the same values as above:

```
CREATE PROC CalculateQty
    @Qty DECIMAL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OnHand AS DECIMAL
    DECLARE @Size AS DECIMAL

    SET @OnHand = 2
    SET @Size = 6

    PRINT (@Qty + @OnHand) / @Size   // result: 6.1666666666666
END

EXEC CalculateQty @Qty=35
```

At the same time when `@Size = 2.5` it is making round off and become 3. I think it's due to variable datatype `decimal` and also I cannot declare float, because it throws error when I use the variable to calculate remainder using `% modulo`

Comment: You can use FLOOR around the divide statement and please declare your decimals with a presision and scale. Not just type DECIMAL. Its bad practice. Write Decimal(18,3) fx - And shouldt 35+2 % 6 give 1 ? it gives 37 and can be divded with 6 which gives 1 left over

Answer (score 0):

As given in the example in [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the way to get the quotient in SQL Server when dividing decimals is to CAST the operation as an integer:

```
DECLARE @Qty decimal
DECLARE @OnHand AS DECIMAL
DECLARE @Size AS DECIMAL

SET @Qty = 35;
SET @OnHand = 2;
SET @Size = 6;

PRINT CAST((@Qty + @OnHand) / @Size AS Integer); --results in 6
```

Also according to [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the default scale of a Decimal data type is 0, so if you do not provide one when you declare the variable, then there will be no digits to the right of the decimal point, and `1.5` will be stored as `2`.

If you assign a sufficient value to the Scale parameter of your decimals, you will get the results you expect:

```
DECLARE @Qty decimal(10,2)
DECLARE @OnHand AS DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @Size AS DECIMAL(10,2)

SET @Qty = 35;
SET @OnHand = 1.5;
SET @Size = 2.5;

PRINT CAST((@Qty + @OnHand) / @Size AS Integer); --results in 14
Print (@Qty + @OnHand) % @Size   --results in 1.50
```